# How can I use a for loop to create four columns in each row using bootstrap 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, for-loop, pug

I've seen similar questions asked but all those were referring to Django and other template systems that I am not familiar with. But essentially I have data being pulled in and I would like to use a for loop to create four columns inside a row and repeat. The code below works however, in the console it shows that I am just creating a bunch of 'span3' one after another. For the most part they end up being four pictures in a row but occasionally they don't clear or two pictures will be on a row, etc. How can I clean up my code so that only four pictures 'span3' go into a row and then the four loop repeats? I hope the code is clear I'm using jade.

```
block body
-var    maxCols = 12;
-var    col = 3;

div(ng-controller='ImgCtrl')
    div(id="wrap")
        div(id="header")
            img(src="stumblr-logo.png", height="60px")
        div(id="main_full")
            div.container
                div.row
                    -for (var i = 0; i < (media.length / col); i++)
                            div(class="span3", id="id")
                                p
                                    a(href="/single?id=#{media[i].image_id}&img=#{media[i].image}")
                                        img(src="#{media[i].image}")
```

Comment: I should probably mention that I've used bootstraps '.controls-row' to clear but that either does nothing or puts each picture in it's own row.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me (Using jade with bootstrap scaffolding)

```
- var cols = 6, elementsInRow = 12/cols
- each _, x in myPosts
    - if ((x % elementsInRow == 0))
         div(class='row-fluid')
             - each post, y in myPosts.slice(x, x+elementsInRow)
                 include ../includes/post
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the each statement in Jade combined with a javascript slice should do what you want.  I don't have your data to test, but I believe your code rewritten like this should do the trick.

```
block body

div(ng-controller='ImgCtrl')
    div(id="wrap")
        div(id="header")
            img(src="stumblr-logo.png", height="60px")
        div(id="main_full")
            div.container
                - each element, x in media
                    - if ((x % 4 == 0))
                        div.row
                            - each elementInRow, y in media.slice(x, x+4)
                                div(class="span3", id="id")
                                    p
                                        a(href="/single?id=#{media[x+y].image_id}&img=#{media[x+y].image}")
                                            img(src="#{media[x+y].image}")
```